# ¿Cómo cambiar href de un tag <a> según ancho de pantalla?

Tags: javascript, html, responsive, href

Me gustaría saber si es posible cambiar el atributo de un tag `<a>` según el ancho del dispositivo que lo esté visualizando. Por ejemplo, en mi caso en una página llamada `index.html` tengo el siguiente codigo:

```
    <div class="content">
     <ul class="actions">
      <li><a id="link1" class="button" href="bearings.html">Learn More</a>
      </li>
     </ul>
    </div>
```

Mi idea es que si el dispositivo tiene un ancho de pantalla menor de 500px me lleve a `imagenes.html`, pero si es mayor me lleve a `bearings.html` para eso he intentado usar el siguiente código en javascript, pero no funciona.

```
<script type="text/javascript">
   $( window ).resize(function() {
       if($( window ).width() < 500) { 
          $("a#link1").attr("href","bearings.html");
       } else {             
          $("a#link1").attr("href","imagenes.html");
       }
    });
</script>
```

Comment: Con ese código cambias la propiedad `src` del elemento no la `href`

Comment: Prueba con if (screen.width<500)

Comment: y como y como se cambia la propiedad href?

Comment: con if (screen.width<500) tampoco funciona

Comment: ¿Con esos cambios te sigue sin funcionar?

Comment: Se puede hacer con media queries, solo con html y css, dando clases ocultando o mostrando las clases según medida

Answer (score 2):

El atributo o propiedad que deberías cambiar es `href`, no `src`.

Puedes hacerlo de la siguiente forma. Le he dado un poco más de claridad al código, usando variables y un operador ternario. Al final establecemos la propiedad del enlace. Es posible que en este caso sea mejor usar  `prop` en vez de `attr`, aunque generalmente funcionará con ambos.

La función quedaría así:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
   $( window ).resize(function() {
         var elLink = $("a#link1");
         var winSize = $(window).width();
         var propLink = (winSize < 500) ? 'bearings.html' : 'imagenes.html';
         elLink.prop('href', propLink);

    });
</script>
```

**Un snippet de prueba:**

```js
var elLink = $("a#link1");
var winSize = $(window).width();
var propLink = (winSize < 500) ? 'bearings.html' : 'imagenes.html';

elLink.prop('href', propLink);
//Prueba
console.log('El link es ahora ' + propLink);
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="content">
  <ul class="actions">
    <li><a id="link1" class="button" href="bearings.html">Learn More</a>
    </li>
  </ul>
</div>
```

---

### Con Javascript puro

Esto se puede hacer también con Javascript puro, prescindiendo de la librería jQuery, obteniendo el tamaño de la ventana con [`innerWidth`](https://developer.mozilla.org/es/docs/Web/API/Window/innerWidth).

```js
var elLink = document.getElementById('link1');
var winSize = window.innerWidth;
var propLink = (winSize < 500) ? 'bearings.html' : 'imagenes.html';
elLink.href=propLink;
console.log('El link es ahora ' + propLink);
```

```html
<div class="content">
  <ul class="actions">
    <li><a id="link1" class="button" href="bearings.html">Learn More</a>
    </li>
  </ul>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

Creo que se debería indicar que se ejecute la funcionalidad que buscas no solo al hacer resize a la window sino también al iniciar el DOM, ya que si inicias con un size mayor a 500px te va a tomar `bearings.html` mientras no hagas resize.

```js
$link1 = $('a#link1')
$currentHref = $('#currentHref')
$currentWidth = $('#currentWidth')

const widthBreakpoint = 500

$(document).ready(assignHref)

$(window).resize(assignHref)

function assignHref() {
  const windowWidth = $(this).width()
  const assignedHref = windowWidth < widthBreakpoint ? 'bearings.html' : 'imagenes.html'
  $link1.attr('href', assignedHref)
  $currentWidth.html(windowWidth)
  $currentHref.html(assignedHref)
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="content">
 <ul class="actions">
  <li><a id="link1" class="button" href="bearings.html">Learn More</a>
  </li>
 </ul>
</div>

<div>href actual: <span id="currentHref"></span></div>
<div>width actual: <span id="currentWidth"></span>px</div>
```